# How to use environment variables in travis-ci

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to get Travis-CI set up but builds are failing because the environment variables aren't getting set. The content of the .travis.yml file is below. I would expect the build log to show `export REQ_FILE=...` but it does not.

```
sudo: false

language: python

python:
  - "2.7"
  - "3.6"

env:
  - REQ_FILE = "./ci/min_reqs.txt"
  - REQ_FILE = "./ci/reqs.txt"

before_install:
  - pip install -r $REQ_FILE

install:
  - pip install .

script:
  - tests/run_tests
```

Complete details:
https://github.com/NREL/rdtools/tree/setup_CI_md
https://travis-ci.org/NREL/rdtools/builds/405012012

Comment: All of the examples [in the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) do not include spaces; did you see whether that is a requirement?

Comment: That fixes it, thank you. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @mdeceglie Someone should post an answer in case anyone else comes looking here. It can be you, but someone should

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to delete the spaces around the equals sign when you are setting your environment variables.

```
env:
  - REQ_FILE="./ci/min_reqs.txt"
  - REQ_FILE="./ci/reqs.txt"
```

Comment: As originally mentioned by @jonrsharpe